# Wait X time, then continue with the loop - JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, delay, timedelay

I have a loop that cycles around and creates REST Queries, creating and running a different one each time.

In the future I imagine the number of REST Queries that could be made will increase far higher than the browser will take at once (over 20,000).

I want to do something along the lines of counting how many loops have been done, and after every 500 or so, pausing for a few seconds to allow the browser to catch up with the REST responses, and then continuing.

How is this done in react JS?

example code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  query += i; 
  axious.get(query) . then { ...does stuff here... } 
  //want something along the lines of if multiple of 500, wait(1000)

}
```

Comment: at least I did not get at all what you mean by the question, but just in case if you are doing that for loading heavy data, read about Lazy Loading in React

Comment: Do you want to pause the thread execution, have you tried `setTimeout`? Because there are other ways but I really don't recommend them.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov I thought setTimeout was only for calling functions? Since it is inside a loop and I'm not calling a function how would that work?

Comment: You should be using functions to do what you are asking and not looping everything at once. Also sounds like you should be using websockets instead of ajax

Comment: You might succeed in having the browser catch up with all the REST requests. But, if you have to make 20k requests, you might want to reconsider the solution. For one, Imagine the stress on backend when you would have concurrent users!

Comment: @AnandUndavia yeah, it won't be our long term solution, thankfully this is an outlying case for specific situations, so we shouldn't run into a clash before we can put a different plan in place!

Answer (score 0):

the simplest approach is to make a `waitIf` function that returns a `Promise` and accepts a condition. 
If the condition is `true`, it will wait then execute the callback, otherwise, it will execute the callback directly.

a simple implementation would be.

```
function waitIf(condition, duration, callback) {


    if (condition) {
        // return a Promise that wait for a `duration` ms using timeout 
        return Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(callback());
            }, duration);
        })
    }

    return callback();
}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    query += i;

    // unify the call here
    waitIf(i % 500 === 0, 1000, () => axious.get(query)).then();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when I use it in my system it works correctly in that it loops until it meets 500, then goes into the if code, and fails on return Promise with the error "undefined is not a promise". Tried to debug this but not getting very far, any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: Solved this by initialising the promise with 'new'. - now I am wondering how even when it gets to the wait if, it doesn't actually stop the axious.get at all, it loops through all possibilities whilst only pausing for the 500th, 501 etc, continues as normal